# mBed: Load external binaries on-demand

Tags: mbed

This is a very high-level/stupid question about mBed...

From what I've seen so far, all libraries and external binaries are bundled into one bin file before deployed to a device. 
My question is, would it be possible for an mBed application to download other binaries and load then on-demand (provided of course that these assemblies implemented a specific interface)? In other words; use binaries that is not part of the original bin file.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really. C/C++ are compiled, not interpreted languages. Technically you could run a C++ interpreter (like [Ch](http://www.softintegration.com)), but I don't think this'll run on a microcontroller due to memory constraints.